# When does the virtual snail shop open?

Tags: here-comes-niko

How do I access the shop for my virtual pet snail? The shop has been closed every time I've checked.

[image: shop is closed]

Answer (score 1):

Each time you swap between another screen and the shop screen on the snail device it refreshes. Just pressing X then B once or twice should make it be "Open"!

I bought out the entire shop for the achievement in a couple of minutes of just doing this.